# Error "Could not find publish settings" while Creating Azure VM via powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, azure

I'm trying to follow these directions to create a VM within Azure using the Azure Powershell.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/

**Cmdlet #1**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

**Cmdlet #2**

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1'
```

**Cmdlet #3**

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

Cmdlet #3 results in the following error:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Could not find publish settings. Please run
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile], FileNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Subscription.GetAzurePublishSettingsFileCommand
```

So far MS has recommended the following which have had no effect:

- Run Azure Powershell as administrator (I am)
- Log into Azure Mgt Portal using IE and visit following URL: https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.asp (I get a 404 error at that URL).
- Try that same URL in IE while in private browsing mode (no difference)

I do see that at least one other person was able to get that URL to work for them here : http://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/get-azurepublishsettingsfile-could-not-find-publish-settings-please-run-import-azurepublishsettingsfile/

Thanks in advance for any additional suggestions on a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the publishprofile url - it ends in `aspx`:

https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx

Once you fix that, you'll be able to download your profile and import it.

Comment: I had to double-check my email from MS support....  the typo was theirs.  But that did the trick.  Thanks!